# How to load data dynamically on scrolling from database using jsp and servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I am trying to load images with title and desc etc dynamically into  on scrolling from database but i don't know how to do this.

Comment: Hi sandeep , actually i tried javascript code to load

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Infinite Scroll: http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

Infinite Scroll Github: https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll

Use an ajax call to fetch data.

If you need more help understanding Infinite Scroll, Google it, you will find plenty of examples.

Answer (score -1):

```
        function yHendler()
        {
            var div = document.getElementById('#div');
            var containtHeight = div.offsetHeight;
            var yOffset = window.pageYOffset;
            var y =  yOffset + window.innerHeight;
            if(y >= containtHeight)
                {
                wrap.innerHTML += '<div class="newData"></div>';
                }
        }
        window.onscroll = yHendler;
```